# Tmdb API appended

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to I add the series_id to this link

[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/{series_id}/aggregate_credits](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/%7Bseries_id%7D/aggregate_credits)

I have a class model with the id but I don’t know how to append it to the link

I’m seeing some people use getX but I’m not familiar with getX. I’m only familiar with provider

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you have a variable:

```
String seriesId = “12345”;
```

You would add it to your URL like this:

```dart
// notice the $ (dollar sign) and the curly braces before the seriesId
String url = “https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${seriesId}/aggregate_credits”;
```

Now if you test it:

```
print(url);
```

You get:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/12345/aggregate_credits
```

This is called string interpolation and you can read more about it [here](https://dart.dev/language/built-in-types#strings).

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider clicking on the green checkmark to mark it as correct.